# SVG loses color/styling when put on a canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

I have been trying to add an svg on top of a png, but when doing so the svg loses all of its styling/coloring.
Both output maps are urls to a webpage.

`const Canvas = require("@napi-rs/canvas");`

```
const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 700);
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const background = await Canvas.loadImage(output["map"]);
context.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
const forground = await Canvas.loadImage(output["map2"])
context.drawImage(forground,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
```

Below is the svg the url leads to

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" class="creatureMap" style="position:absolute;">
<defs>
<filter id="blur" x="-30%" y="-30%" width="160%" height="160%"><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" />
</filter>
<pattern id="pattern-untameable" width="10" height="10" patternTransform="rotate(135)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><rect width="4" height="10" fill="black"></rect>
</pattern>
<filter id="groupStroke"><feFlood result="outsideColor" flood-color="black"/><feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" operator="dilate" radius="2"/><feComposite result="strokeoutline1" in="outsideColor" operator="in"/><feComposite result="strokeoutline2" in="strokeoutline1" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="out"/><feGaussianBlur in="strokeoutline2" result="strokeblur" stdDeviation="1"/>
</filter>
<style>
.spawningMap-very-common { fill: #0F0;}
.spawningMap-common { fill: #B2FF00;}
.spawningMap-uncommon { fill: #FF0;}
.spawningMap-very-uncommon { fill: #FC0;}
.spawningMap-rare { fill: #F60;}
.spawningMap-very-rare { fill: #F00; }.spawning-map-point {stroke:black; stroke-width:1;}
</style>
</defs>
<g filter="url(#blur)" opacity="0.7">
<g class="spawningMap-rare"><rect x="183" y="155" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="79" y="168" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="79" y="180" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="79" y="193" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="105" y="168" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="92" y="168" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="92" y="180" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="92" y="193" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="131" y="142" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="118" y="155" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="118" y="180" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="131" y="193" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="118" y="193" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="157" y="142" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="144" y="142" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="157" y="180" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="144" y="193" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="183" y="142" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="170" y="142" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="170" y="155" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="183" y="168" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="170" y="168" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="196" y="142" width="11" height="12" /><rect x="196" y="155" width="11" height="11" />
</g>
<g class="spawningMap-very-uncommon"><rect x="260" y="142" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="260" y="155" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="260" y="168" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="247" y="168" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="273" y="142" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="53" y="193" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="66" y="193" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="66" y="206" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="79" y="206" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="79" y="218" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="66" y="218" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="92" y="206" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="105" y="206" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="118" y="206" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="131" y="206" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="118" y="218" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="157" y="193" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="144" y="206" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="157" y="206" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="157" y="218" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="170" y="180" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="183" y="218" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="170" y="218" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="196" y="180" width="11" height="12" /><rect x="196" y="193" width="11" height="11" /><rect x="196" y="206" width="11" height="11" /><rect x="196" y="218" width="11" height="12" /><rect x="221" y="142" width="12" height="12" /><rect x="221" y="155" width="12" height="11" /><rect x="234" y="168" width="12" height="11" />
</g>
<g class="spawningMap-very-common"><rect x="115" y="193" width="2" height="2" /><rect x="112" y="193" width="3" height="2" /><rect x="117" y="191" width="2" height="4" /><rect x="112" y="188" width="4" height="4" /><rect x="108" y="193" width="2" height="2" /><rect x="255" y="137" width="8" height="10" /><rect x="247" y="138" width="8" height="11" /><rect x="116" y="188" width="3" height="4" />
</g>
</g>
<g class="spawning-map-point" opacity="0.8">
</g>
<g fill="url(#pattern-untameable)" opacity="0.3"><rect x="115" y="193" width="2" height="2"/><rect x="112" y="193" width="3" height="2"/><rect x="117" y="191" width="2" height="4"/><rect x="112" y="188" width="4" height="4"/><rect x="108" y="193" width="2" height="2"/><rect x="255" y="137" width="8" height="10"/><rect x="247" y="138" width="8" height="11"/><rect x="116" y="188" width="3" height="4"/>
</g>
<g filter="url(#groupStroke)" opacity="0.8"><rect x="115" y="193" width="2" height="2"/><rect x="112" y="193" width="3" height="2"/><rect x="117" y="191" width="2" height="4"/><rect x="112" y="188" width="4" height="4"/><rect x="108" y="193" width="2" height="2"/><rect x="255" y="137" width="8" height="10"/><rect x="247" y="138" width="8" height="11"/><rect x="116" y="188" width="3" height="4"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Show the content of your svg file please